# Use of threads with fragments

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

Hi I have just started developping in android so I'am not  an expert. My question is:
I am creating an application with two fragments , both the fragments have to retrive data from a service in real-time. (In particular on fragment has to draw a plot using the data read and the other has to make move an avatar with the data read, all of this in real-time).My doubt is: do I have to use two threads, one for each fragments, or I can do this with just a thread ?

thanks for your answers and please let me know if my question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The best option you can do is to learn first how to properly use certain libraries that may help you to do what you have described (as always, things related to Networking are not an easy or a trivial part in an application).

I propose you to read some things related that may be helpful:

- [Android Developer Documentation about Threads and Processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)
- [Best Practices for Consuming Apis on Android](http://engineering.meetme.com/2014/03/best-practices-for-consuming-apis-on-android/)
- [Durable Android Rest Clients](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2014/04/07/durable-android-rest-clients.html)

The last link presents you a great workflow on how to do several parts when dealing with Networking and Intercommunication (like using a Bus). It's related to consuming restful services but much applies to other kind of data.

Libraries like [Android Priority JobQueue](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue) made by Yigit at Path helps you when dealing with background operations.

If you need more concrete answers please specify more what you want to do and I would gladly help you! :)

Comment: Hi :D

I'm a friend of the author of this question :)

I answer to @Aldo Borrero.

We have to receive data from a bluetooth 4.0 BLE sensor, and we have to send it to two diffent fragments
In one  we have to plot a 2d graph with AndroidPlot

In the other we have to move a 3d rigged model using jpct-ae + bones

We wanted to use a started service to handle bluetooth (by extending IntentService) , but we have a lot of doubts. If two fragments have to work in the same time we have to use two different threads ?